# keyCode returns 'undefined' (react)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to trigger a function when someone presses 'Enter'. In my function, when I console.log the keyCode, it returns 'undefined'. I've tried .keyCode, .which, .key, .code, but all of them return undefined. Here is my code:

```
handleLineCount = (event) => {
        console.log(event.keyCode);
        let charCount = event.length;
        let myIndex = 0;

        this.setState({
            charCount: charCount,
        });

        if(charCount === 5 && event.keyCode !== 8 || event.keyCode === 13){
            myIndex++; 

            this.setState({
                lines: [...this.state.lines, myIndex]
            })
        }
    }
```

How do I get the value of the keyCode when passing in the event value into the function? This is an onChange event. I've also tried using an onKeyDown event, an onKeyUp event, an onKeyPress event and the keyCode is always 'undefined'.

Here is the element it is bind to:

```
<textarea 
  id="first-line"
  placeholder="this is a test to count line numbers..." 
  style={{width: "60%", padding: "10px 10px 0", boxSizing: "border-box"}}
  maxlength="5"
  onChange={(e) => this.handleLineCount(e.target.value)}/>
```

Comment: can you add the element that is bind to the function?

Comment: try `console.log(Object.keys(event))` to see what kind of things are in it

Comment: I just added the element it is bind to

Comment: Object.keys(event) returns empty arrays

Comment: Can you create a [small demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this using codepen or codesandbox to show the issue happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have more about [events](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html) in react

But long story short:

use `nativeEvent` to access keyCode, since event in arguments is synthetic event sent by react and in there you have `event.nativeEvent.keyCode`

**EDIT**

You should pass only e to function not e.target.value

```
<textarea 
   id="first-line"
   placeholder="this is a test to count line numbers..." 
   style={{width: "60%", padding: "10px 10px 0", boxSizing: "border-box"}}
   maxlength="5"
   onChange={(e) => this.handleLineCount(e)}
/>
```

Comment: Just tried this and got the error code: Cannot read property 'keyCode' of undefined

Comment: just tried only passing in e with the .nativeEvent.keyCode and still got 'undefined'

Comment: use in `textarea` `onChange={this.handleLineCount}`, and in function  ... `(event)=> { console.log(event.nativeEvent)}` and see what it's logs out

Comment: This was part of the solution. Thanks! See my comment on Dennis Vash answer to see the full solution.

Comment: glad to hear that, please just mark this answer as solution

Comment: you don't need ```nativeEvent```

Comment: That's not a good answer... You don't have access to `keyCode` in `onChange` and you don't need `nativeEvent`.

Answer (score 2):

You don't pass the `event` object to `handleLineCount`:

```
<textarea onKeyPress={handleLineCount} />
```

[image: Edit festive-lalande-rfw2j]

Comment: just tried this and the keyCode still returns 'undefined'

Comment: use other events, not `onChange`, see attached example

Comment: This worked! Thanks! I put the onKeyPress function within the class component and used this.onKeyPress attached to the onKeyPress event. Also used .nativeEvent.keyCode in the console.log.

Comment: @DennisVash why are you using ```onKeyPress``` instead of  ```onChange```?

Comment: @JuniusL. Thank you for downvoting, you don't have `keyCode` on this event (at least what I checked), check in the sandbox

Comment: dude I'm the first person who upvoted your answer, and I took my upvote as you are using ```onKeyPress``` instead of ```onChange```.

Comment: Can you show an example of calling `onChange` and using `keyCode`? @JuniusL.

Comment: I just checked your codesandbox and onChange doesn't have keyCode

Answer (score 0):

You need to send the `event.keyCode`, not the `event.target.value`....

---

```
    <textarea 
     id="first-line"
     placeholder="this is a test to count line numbers..." 
     style={{width: "60%", padding: "10px 10px 0", boxSizing: "border-box"}}
     maxlength="5"
     onKeyDown={e => this.handleLineCount(e.keyCode)}
    />
```

---